# How to backup large contact photos?

Tags: contacts, backup, import, contact-photo, export

Most modern Android devices allow storing large photos of each contact.

I tried exporting all my contacts, then importing them.  All the large photos were lost.

How can you backup the large photos associated with each contact?

Answer (score 3):

**Backup and Restore**

Following the app recommendations made in this XDA post [How to backup local contacts with their high res pictures ?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/how-to-backup-local-contacts-res-t3401287)

I set a hi res `1984 × 1800` picture for contact and backed up using [Super backup: SMS and contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts) , took a backup , deleted the contact and restored

To my eyes, it appeared to be high resolution as originally​ set

The other app was not tried as it was pointed out in app review that it didn't work beyond 720 resolution

I tried to locate the storage of these high resolution pictures to manually verify the restored file size but couldn't. Method described in [Where does android store contact photos ?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1676097) didn't work

---

**Edit**

- The reason I wanted to verify pre and post backup - restore process was to check if hi-res photos were backed up , not wanting to believe my eyes judging the resolution of the picture in a small circle on an LCD screen. So I asked this question [High resolution contact pictures in Marshmallow - what is their size and where are they stored](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179378/131553)
- As iBug explained in the accepted answer the resolution is capped to `720 by 720` irrespective of the picture size , an improvement implemented from [KitKat days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834815/how-to-find-the-max-image-size-supported-for-contacts-images)

It turns out that my suspicion was well founded !

- As an aside, *contact thumbnails* (  used for notifications, messaging applications ) which are scaled down to `96 by 96` can be scaled up to `256 by 256` by this Xposed module [Clarity](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/clarity-contact-thumbnails-don-t-mind-t3063804)

**Bottom Line:** Any contact picture irrespective of original resolution will look no better than a `720 by 720` resolution, whether you use an app , [Gmail sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179378/high-resolution-contact-pictures-in-marshmallow-what-is-their-size-and-where-a/179383#comment230401_179383) or for that matter in any manner